# How disable making auto network requests for mutations when offline in AWS AppSync Client React App?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

Performed a mutation when offline is not throwing the error immediately. AppSync does multiple requests automatically (I guess this is an offline capability) and then after it throws `Error: Network error: Failed to fetch`.

I have added  `disableOffline: true` when creating AppSync client in my react app.

How can I disable this? I want to throw error immediately after the first request fails like traditional REST API calls.(Disable making requests automatically for some time).

Found a github issue for ios here : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios/issues/37.
But didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please show your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt. We're more than happy to then help :)